# Iterating a table row in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eob9W.png) [result page][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToWNW.png) [chooseMedicine page]How do i iterate a table row in my chooseMedicine.jsp page without loosing previous data selected by user on result.jsp page.I am loosing the previous selected medicine when i click on continue shopping.Is this possible by scriptlet tag?.....Thank you for your help.

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("Med")%>"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("NumberOfTab")%>"</td>
<td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("Cost")%>"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("TotalPrice")%>"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is a result.jsp page? How does the user reach chooseMedicine.jsp? What is being selected in result.jsp? Where is the table data coming from?

Comment: do you want to simply include the other jsp?

Comment: No, After i select the 1st medicine i go to the result.jsp page when i click on continue shopping i go back to chooseMedicine and select the 2nd medicine...so the second medicine selected should be shown in the 2nd row along with the first in result.jsp....so how do i do that.... so in order to acheive that i need to iterate the row...right? how do i do that... ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
<% for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ %>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("Med")%>"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("NumberOfTab")%>" </td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("Cost")%>"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<%=request.getAttribute("TotalPrice")%>"/></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```

You can change the for loop condition based on your requirement.

Comment: You can try JSTL as well, @AlanHay.